# Domain-Drive-Design service

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, software-design

I am in the search on the best (or better) approach on writing domain services based on domain-driven-design. Here's the pseudo-code

```
public class CustomerAccount
{
    public string AccountNumber {get; set;}
    public string CustomerName  {get; set;}
    public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}
    public string HomeAddress {get; set;}
}

// Domain Service Class
public class AccountService
{
    public virtual void RefreshAccount( CustomerAccount acct)
    {
        // Some code here to refresh the class from cache... 
        cache.refresh( acct )
    }
}

public static class Cache
{
    public static refresh(CustomerAccount acct)
    {
        // refreshing class here.
    } 
}
```

The question I have is should I have the RefreshAccount() inside the AccountService and call the the it this way? Or just call the cache class directly? Either way works fine but my question concern is, from the design perspective, especially DDD, which way is the best and why?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is `Cache`? Is it some term in the domain? Or is it simply a cache used to reduce I/O for performance reasons?

Comment: @Jakub Yup, it's another domain.

Comment: Usually, caching belongs to the Infrastructure layer, not to the domain layer. The domain service itself doesn't need to know anything about caching (unless caching is really part of the your domain), it's the client (or some intermediary application service) that is to consult the cache. Also, if you need to evict data from the cache based on some domain event, the domain needs to expose this event publicly, and clients (such as the cache service) can be notified and act accordingly.

Comment: I agree with @haim770.  If this were domain functionality you would want to call the domain service and *not* the cache directly.  However, since it really does look like infrastructure the caching will probably reside in an *application* service and in that case it really doesn't matter too much given the `static`.  If you could get rid of the static and rather inject the cache into your application service then even better :)

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments! really helps out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cache` sounds a lot like a part of infrastructure layer, not domain. If that's the case, it should be removed from the domain layer. The domain model should not be polluted with technical complexities.

Assuming that `Cache` really belongs to the domain, it's hard to answer this question without more information about the domain.

In general:

- If `Cache` and `CustomerAccount` are parts of the same aggregate, `Cache` should be accessed from the aggregate root.
- If they are not the same aggregate but still belong to the same bounded context, use a domain service to perform operations that require both `CustomerAccount` and `Cache`.
- If `Cache` belongs to another bounded context, use domain events to notify it.

I would suggest changing the name of `Cache` in the UL if possible. It might cause misunderstandings among the programmers in your team, especially when new people join the team.

Answer (score 0):

DDD and Test Driven Development usually go hand-in-hand so from a TDD perspective you'll want to keep it the way you have it and avoid calling the static refresh method directly; otherwise it will be very hard to unit test properly.

Comment: In fact, static classes/methods are considered an anti-pattern so if you want a true DDD implementation you might want to rethink how you refresh an account.

Comment: What if I take out the "static" keyword? would it make difference in determining what to call? (ie, from the service or the method directly)

Comment: @Dan, Claiming that `static` classes/methods are anti-pattern is wrong (how will you define C# extension-methods then)? A more accurate claim would be that static classes and methods are more prone to abuse when one doesn't understand the real life cycle or structure of his code.